# How to create many-to-many association using GRDB in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, grdb

I'm trying to setup an association between songs and albums. Each song can appear on one or more albums and each album can contain one or more songs. I decided to go with [GRDB](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) for my database solution but I'm stuck on this issue.

What I tried:
As documentation suggests, I created a `passport` struct, like this:

```
public struct AlbumPassport: TableRecord {
    static let track = belongsTo(SPTTrack.self)
    static let album = belongsTo(SPTAlbum.self)
}
```

Then in SPTTrack class:

```
public static let passports = hasMany(AlbumPassport.self)
public static let albums = hasMany(SPTAlbum.self, through: passports, using: AlbumPassport.album)
```

And in SPTAlbum class:

```
public static let passports = hasMany(AlbumPassport.self)
public static let tracks = hasMany(SPTTrack.self, through: passports, using: AlbumPassport.track)
```

I cannot find in the [documentation](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Documentation/AssociationsBasics.md#hasmanythrough) a good example on how to build a request using those associations. In SPTAlbum class I added `linkedTracks` property

```
public var linkedTracks: QueryInterfaceRequest<SPTTrack> {
    request(for: Self.tracks)
}
```

And then in my database manager:

```
func fetchTracks(for album: SPTAlbum) -> [SPTTrack] {
    do {
        return try dbQueue.read { db in
            try album.linkedTracks.fetchAll(db)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return []
}
```

I'm getting error:

> SQLite error 1: no such table: albumPassport

which is pretty self-explanatory, but I have no clue how and where should I create table for the `AlbumPassport` struct and if there are any additional steps I should take to actually populate this table with album/track connections.

Both SPTTrack/SPTAlbum have a field called `id` which is set as `primaryKey` during first migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues with your associations. All `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` are correct. The error you are getting tells me that there is something wrong with your database setup (which you didn't include in your question).

Here is how i would implement it:

[image: Schema]

```swift
import GRDB

struct Album: Codable, Hashable, FetchableRecord, MutablePersistableRecord {
    mutating func didInsert(with rowID: Int64, for column: String?) { id = rowID }
    var id: Int64?
    var name: String
    static let passports = hasMany(AlbumPassport.self)
    static let tracks = hasMany(Track.self, through: passports, using: AlbumPassport.track)
}

struct Track: Codable, Hashable, FetchableRecord, MutablePersistableRecord {
    mutating func didInsert(with rowID: Int64, for column: String?) { id = rowID }
    var id: Int64?
    var name: String
    static let passports = hasMany(AlbumPassport.self)
    static let albums = hasMany(Album.self, through: passports, using: AlbumPassport.album)
}

struct AlbumPassport: Codable, Hashable, FetchableRecord, PersistableRecord {
    let track: Int64
    let album: Int64
    static let track = belongsTo(Track.self)
    static let album = belongsTo(Album.self)
}

let queue = DatabaseQueue()
try queue.write { db in
    
    try db.create(table: "album") { t in
        t.autoIncrementedPrimaryKey("id")
        t.column("name", .text).notNull()
    }
    try db.create(table: "track") { t in
        t.autoIncrementedPrimaryKey("id")
        t.column("name", .text).notNull()
    }
    try db.create(table: "albumPassport") { t in
        t.column("track", .integer).notNull().indexed().references("track")
        t.column("album", .integer).notNull().indexed().references("album")
        t.primaryKey(["track", "album"])
    }
    
    // Testing real data from https://music.apple.com/de/artist/yiruma/73406786
    
    var solo = Album(name: "SOLO")
    try solo.insert(db)
    var sometimes = Track(name: "Sometimes Someone")
    try sometimes.insert(db)
    try AlbumPassport(track: sometimes.id!, album: solo.id!).insert(db)
    var destiny = Track(name: "Destiny Of Love")
    try destiny.insert(db)
    try AlbumPassport(track: destiny.id!, album: solo.id!).insert(db)
    
    var bestOf = Album(name: "Best of Yiroma")
    try bestOf.insert(db)
    var poem = Track(name: "Poem")
    try poem.insert(db)
    try AlbumPassport(track: poem.id!, album: bestOf.id!).insert(db)
    var river = Track(name: "River Flows In You")
    try river.insert(db)
    try AlbumPassport(track: river.id!, album: bestOf.id!).insert(db)
}

// Fetch all albums and their tracks
try queue.read { db in
    struct AlbumInfo: FetchableRecord, Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var album: Album
        var tracks: Set<Track>
        var description: String { "\(album.name) → \(tracks.map(\.name))" }
    }
    let request = Album.including(all: Album.tracks)
    let result = try AlbumInfo.fetchAll(db, request)
    print(result)
    // > [SOLO → ["Sometimes Someone", "Destiny Of Love"], Best of Yiroma → ["River Flows In You", "Poem"]]
}
```

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356274/251839) of [Many-to-many relationship where one entity has multiple properties of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147947/many-to-many-relationship-where-one-entity-has-multiple-properties-of-the-same-t) for another code example.